# How can I add -fobjc-arc for a lot files one time

Tags: ios, xmpp, automatic-ref-counting

I want to add xmppframework to my project, how can I add -fobjc-arc to all xmpp files one time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but is usually good enough:

1. Select the project at the top left of the project window.
2. Select the target.
3. Open the build phases pane.
4. Select "Compile Sources"
5. Type in "xmpp" into the filter area
6. Select the files you want.
7. Hit Enter and then type -fobjc_arc in the dialog.

Comment: I tried this many times , but it just add -fobjc_arc to the cell I click

Comment: I just verified it works in Xcode 4.5.1. You need to select multiple files at once using the shift or command keys and then hit Enter.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug of xcode 4.4.1. I tried more than ten times, but all failed.

Comment: @EricS - I am afraid **-fobjc_arc** has to corrected as **-fobjc-arc**

Answer (score 2):

Simple, in your compiler sources select the first item that requires the flag, scroll down and click the last item while holding the shift key. Then all you have to do is double click any one of the highlighted cells and add the flag and when you hit enter it will be applied to all highlighted files.

Comment: I tried this many times , but it just add -fobjc-arc to the cell I click

Comment: @dustdn I don't know what to tell you then, maybe Xcode needs a reinstall. That's interesting that such a basic function is failing for you.

Comment: Thanks. I should hit enter but not click mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as far as I know. You have to do that one file at a time. You might want to look into your name.xcodeproj directory, perhaps you can edit the project.pbxproj file, though I wouldn't do that